# What happens to previous app installs when running an app on a device from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I'm somewhat new to iOS development and I'm sure this is probably a basic question but I've been wondering about what happens each time you run your app on a physical device from Xcode.  Let's say that my app takes a picture and saves it to the Documents directory.  The first time I run the app, I take a picture and save it as a JPEG to the Documents directory.  The path where the file gets saved is:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/86D12E64-92BA-405D-98C7-E2C3502DE39C/Documents/picture.jpg
```

Now I find a bug in my app so I stop it from Xcode.  I fix the bug and run the app again.  I repeat the steps above and this time I save the picture to the Documents directory and the path is:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4A85B3CF-C578-4733-8AEC-19DEFA3796DE/Documents/picture.jpg
```

From what I understand the part of the path between /Application/ and /Documents represents the "app id" so it's not surprising to me that this seems to change each time I run the app from Xcode.  But what happens to the data on the device's file system from all the previous times that I ran the app from Xcode?  Does Xcode uninstall previous app installations and effectively remove that directory from the file system?  Thanks for explaining what is probably a silly question!

Answer (score 0):

It's expected behaviour. iOS 8 onwards, the URL to app's sandbox changes every time you relaunch the app for security reasons. Hence you should never store the absolute URL of the directory. You should access the path using File API every time like the following:

```
let directoryURL: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let fileURL: URL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("picture.jpg")
```

The actual URL is changed every launch (virtually), but OS maps correctly the directly when you use before if you use the API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand that the sandbox changes each time I run the app and I'm using the code that you reference to determine the path to the Documents directory.  What I'm wondering about is what happens to the data that I created previously when I stop the app and run it again?  Does running my app from Xcode result in the previous instance of the app being uninstalled and therefore the "old" data in the previous sandbox is removed?  I'm assuming this is the case because otherwise, if I ran the app enough, I could fill up the filesystem which doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: If you overwrite the app from Xcode, the old data remains and you can access it. If you uninstall the app from the device or simulator, then install the app from Xcode, the data is wiped. Because you uninstall the app.

Comment: Xcode renames the directory, so that existing data is preserved and doesn't take up additional disk space.